# How to get the input value in my case?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to get the user input value via ng-model in my case

I have

```
<div ng-controller="test">
    <input type="input" ng-model="title"/>
    <button type="button" ng-click="save()">Save</button>
</div>
```

js

```
app.controller('test', function ($scope) {

    $scope.save = function() {
        console.log($scope.title)  -> undefined.....
    }
})
```

I am not sure why `$scope.title` is `undefined`. I want to get the input value. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried to put your <button> inside of your ng-controller "domain"?

Comment: @FelipeKM Sorry, my button is actually inside the test controller. thanks for pointing out

Comment: Doesnt make much sense...if that function is being called, then `title` is most certainly on the `$scope` - if you can reproduce in a fiddle I'd be surprised

Comment: Is undefined because you haven't set a value. If you initialize the variable inside your controller will show the initial value. If not, ant if you put some text on your input will show that value.

Comment: your code is working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/4GtxC/

Comment: It's not necessary to initialize it, ng-model do it.

Comment: @FelipeKM unless he is not typing a value into the input, in that case ng-model initialize the value to undefined

Comment: @MaxiBaez He just disappeared, I'm pretty sure that he fixed it, surely he missed something out. lol

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the scope variable when the controller loads:

```
app.controller('test', function ($scope) {
    $scope.title = '';
    $scope.save = function() {
        console.log($scope.title)  -> undefined.....
    }
```

})

Answer (score 0):

Probably a scoping problem, your button not belongs to "test" controller. 
Try this :

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <input type="input" ng-model="title"/>
    <button type="button" ng-click="save()">Save</button>
 </div>
```

see the running demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gm5K8/)

It's not necessary to initialize "title", ng-model do it for your. Unless if you are not typing a value into the input, in that case ng-model initialize "title" to undefined.

Answer (score -1):

Try to inject your $scope as below:

```
app.controller("test", ["$scope", function ($scope) {

    $scope.save = function() {
        console.log($scope.title);
    };

}]);
```

Comment: Yeah I know, but I'm just trying to expose a lil bit diff scenario, cause I couldn't reproduce the error as exposed here.

Comment: This is just for testing sake , it does nothing with $scope or anyhitng else